# Unable to build mobile MonoGame project because of a "could not import" error

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, monogame

I am making a mobile MonoGame application for the first time but whenever I try and build this error occurs for iOS

```
Error: /Users/edward/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/apps/Xamarin/Android/Radiant/iOS/Radiant.iOS.csproj: /Users/edward/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/apps/Xamarin/Android/Radiant/iOS/Radiant.iOS.csproj could not import "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" (Radiant.iOS)
```

and this error occurs for Android

```
Error: /Users/edward/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/apps/Xamarin/Android/Radiant/Android/Radiant.Droid.csproj: /Users/edward/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/apps/Xamarin/Android/Radiant/Android/Radiant.Droid.csproj could not import "$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" (Radiant.Droid)
```

On the left in the references column, MonoGame.Framework is greyed out and there is a red X next to it

Comment: Looks like you need to resolve the reference to MonoGame framework. Try removing the reference and adding it back.

Comment: @jjhavokk I tried that but when I click edit references to re add it, monogame doesn't show up and when I tried to remove the addin and re add it, it didn't show up in the installed addins or addin store either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was able to figure it out on my own, I went to the [MonoGame addin page](http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/47) and I downloaded the stable release. I then opened up the addin list in Xamarin and I clicked install from file. I selected the stable release I downloaded and then installed it from there. It gave me an error about MonoDevelop but I just ignored it and it worked fine.